# How to properly use multiple Middlewares in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, middleware

I have an api route group in which i want to use multiple middleware classes on, however, Laravel seems to be totally disregarding my additional middleware:

```
// API ROUTE
Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'additional']], function () {
    Route::post('api/route', 'apiController@index');
});

// REGISTER ADDITIONAL MIDDLEWARE IN KERNEL
protected $routeMiddleware = [
  'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
  'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
   ...
  'additional' => \App\Http\Middleware\Additional::class
];
// ADDITIONAL MIDDLEWARE CLASS
class Additional
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return Log::info($request);

        // return $next($request);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in the middleware class i expect to log out the `$request` and i also commented out the `$next` func, however my app just disregards this & displays my home view...

Comment: Is the user logged in when doing this? If not, that would explain why you're being redirected back to the home page.

Comment: forgive me as i am fairly new to laravel, how do i treat these api endpoints almost like a stateless webhook? no authentication needed just pass a few middleware to it? @Mike

Comment: According to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#via-middleware `auth:api` makes sure the user provides a valid access token to authenticate. If you don't require that, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the middleware in protected **$middlewareGroups** array in kernel rather than in the    **protected $routeMiddleware** in the kernal.php